# Warning: Visibility for constructor is ignored. If you want the contract to be non-deployable, making it "abstract" is sufficient

Tags: ethereum, solidity

Hi everyone I want to smart contract at solidity. But I get the following warning

Warning: Visibility for constructor is ignored. If you want the contract to be non-deployable, making it "abstract" is sufficient. I can't fixed help me please

this is the code i got warning

```
 constructor(address exampleExternalContractAddress) public {
      exampleExternalContract = ExampleExternalContract(exampleExternalContractAddress);
     
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs page [Solidity v0.7.0 Breaking Changes](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/070-breaking-changes.html):

> *Visibility (`public` / `internal`) is not needed for constructors anymore*

The constructor is executed only once - during the contract deployment - so the visibility is not needed anyway.

**Solution**: Remove the `public` visibility modifier from the constructor.

```
constructor(address exampleExternalContractAddress) {
      exampleExternalContract = ExampleExternalContract(exampleExternalContractAddress);     
}
```